# IBM Bluemix Services on node-red local instance

Tags: ibm-cloud, node-red

I have installed node-red and node-red Bluemix services in my machine (Fedora 22) using the following commands

```
sudo npm install -g node-red 
sudo npm install node-red-bluemix-nodes
```

Then I run command

```
$ node-red
```

and open localhost:1880

However I can't see any Bluemix Services like speech-to-text.

Any idea how to get the Bluemix Services on node-red local instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In what directory did you run the npm install of the Bluemix nodes?

It should be run in ~/.node-red so that the node module appears in ~/.node-red/node_modules/node-red-bluemix-nodes.